# how to select 3 random items of each category?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help writing a select query basically I have the table structured as below:

```
cat_prod
----------
cid | pid
----------
 1 | 1
 2 | 2
 3 | 3
 4 | 4
 5 | 5
 1 | 2
 2 | 3
 3 | 4
 4 | 5
 5 | 1
 1 | 3
 2 | 4
 3 | 5
 4 | 1
 5 | 2
```

Now I would like to select at least 3 random pid's of each cid where it exists or the maximum pid's if less than 3, how would i do that in one query? Baring in mind I would like the query to be as efficent as possible and that the table data is likely to grow considerablly.

Thanks

Comment: This [post](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/) might be helpful.

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495446/how-to-get-random-records-from-each-category-in-mysql/31496011?noredirect=1#comment50972156_31496011

Answer (score 0):

Although some changes might be needed, the following query is almost appropriate:

```
select C.cid, C.pid
from cat_prod C
where C.pid in (select c1.pid from cat_prod c1 order by (pid) limit 3);
```

Comment: Randomize that and you're there :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response, it didn't work for me I get an error: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' is there a way to rewrite this?

Thanks